# Custom Url scheme to open file

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, launch, url-scheme

Ive searched a lot of docs maybe im just not reading the right ones. I want to create a custom url scheme that opens a specified path so i.e. customSheme://desktop/videoFile.mov and have the default application open the file.

Answer (score 1):

Open notepad and paste the code below into it. Change "YourApp" into your app's name. Save it to YourApp.reg and execute it by clicking on it in explorer. YourApp Protocol is the name of your protocol.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp]
@="URL:YourApp Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\YourApp\\YourApp.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\YourApp\\YourApp.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\" \"%9\""
```

This is kind of dodgy and unofficial.  You're not really MEANT to do this.
These things are supposed to be officially registered
https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml
You can do a lot with the existing URI schemes, you might be able to find another way to solve this.

Comment: i get that that will open an app that i specify. I only want to open a file path be it a text doc or a mp4

Comment: so ive done everything and set the path to explorer.exe and nothing happens when i click i link im not sure if theres more i need to do web page side